# php select option from dropdown

Tags: php, mysqli

I am working on a project I need to select option from html dropdown list and then display the data selected from database. Just like filter and display the filtered data from database. 
Still not working
Am getting error:

> Its just displaying all data from db not by filtered query

```
<form action="search.php" method="POST">
<div class="md-form">
<select class="mdb-select" name="state_search" required>
<option disabled selected>Choose your State</option>
<option name="state" value="Abia State">Abia State</option>
<option name="state" value="Adamawa State">Adamawa State</option>
<option name="state" value="Anambra State">Anambra State</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
<div class="md-form">
<select class="mdb-select" name="school_search">
<option value="" disabled selected>Choose your School</option>
<option value="Michael Opkara University">Mouau</option>
<option value="University of Benin">UniBen</option>
<option value="University of Porthacourt">UniPort</option>
</select>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn purple-gradient btn-lg" name="filter">Search <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o ml-1"></i></button>
</div>
</form>
```

PHP

```
        <?php
$school_search = $connect->real_escape_string($_POST["school_search"]);
$state_search = $connect->real_escape_string($_POST["state_search"]);

$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM roomate WHERE (`state` LIKE '%".$state_search."%') OR (`school` LIKE '%".$school_search."%')") or die(mysql_error());
if($query){
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    ?>
    <div class="container" style="padding-top:70px;">
    <!--Grid row-->
      <div class="row">
        <?php
        foreach ($query  as $user) {?>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-r">
            <!--Featured image-->
            <div class="overlay hm-white-slight z-depth-1-half mb-2">
              <img src="<?php echo $user['room_avatar']?>" class="img-fluid" alt="avatar image">
              <a><div class="mask"></div></a>
            </div>
            <!--Excerpt-->
            <a href="" class="pink-text">
              <h6>
                <i class="fa fa-map"></i><strong><?php echo $user['city'];?>, <?php echo $user['state'];?></strong><br>
                <small><?php echo $user['school'];?></small>
              </h6>
            </a>
            <h4><?php echo $user['type'];?></h4>
            <p>
              by <a><strong><?php echo $user['room_name'];?></strong></a>
              <?php echo $user['created'];?>
            </p>
            <label class="badge badge-danger"> non-verified </label>
            <a href="contact.php">
              <label class="badge badge-primary">Report Scam</label>
            </a>
            <p><?php echo $user['discription'];?></p>
            <a class="btn btn-pink btn-rounded">Contact <?php echo $user['room_name'];?></a>
          </div>
        <?php
        } ?>  
      </div>      
    </div>
    <?php
  }
}
else{
  echo(mysql_error());
}

?>
```

Need help making this work out

Comment: whats your question? what errors are you getting?

Comment: please recheck edited. am trying to filter data as search from db and display the data as search result. Error: its not working displaying all data from db instead of specific query.

Answer (score 0):

The name of your `select` needs to match the `$_POST` variable key.

So in your case your `<select>` need the name `state_search`.

or change your `$_POST` search to `$_POST['state']` to match your select name.

also you should use the `$state_search` variable in your query instead of `$query`.

You may have more issues , just pay attention to details.

Answer (score 0):

You put to much HTML in echo function.

```
<?php
$school_search = $connect->real_escape_string($_POST["school_search"]);
$state_search = $connect->real_escape_string($_POST["state_search"]);

$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM roomate WHERE (`room_name` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`discription` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`discription` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`type` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());;
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
if($result){
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
    <div class="container" style="padding-top:70px;">
    <!--Grid row-->
      <div class="row">
        <?php
        foreach ($query  as $user) {?>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-r">
            <!--Featured image-->
            <div class="overlay hm-white-slight z-depth-1-half mb-2">
              <img src="<?php echo $user['room_avatar']?>" class="img-fluid" alt="avatar image">
              <a><div class="mask"></div></a>
            </div>
            <!--Excerpt-->
            <a href="" class="pink-text">
              <h6>
                <i class="fa fa-map"></i><strong><?php echo $user['city'];?>, <?php echo $user['state'];?></strong><br>
                <small><?php echo $user['school'];?></small>
              </h6>
            </a>
            <h4><?php echo $user['type'];?></h4>
            <p>
              by <a><strong><?php echo $user['room_name'];?></strong></a>
              <?php echo $user['created'];?>
            </p>
            <label class="badge badge-danger"> non-verified </label>
            <a href="contact.php">
              <label class="badge badge-primary">Report Scam</label>
            </a>
            <p><?php echo $user['discription'];?></p>
            <a class="btn btn-pink btn-rounded">Contact <?php echo $user['room_name'];?></a>
          </div>
        <?php
        } ?>  
      </div>      
    </div>
    <?php
  }
}
else{
  echo(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: If you echo $state_search; after it is defined, what you get?